# Rules for tables having segregated data for each company

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my firebase app, each user belongs to a company (a company may have many users), and data in tables is split into Table_name\COMPANY_ID\

COMPANY_ID is defined in the Users table.

Like for e.g Items table would be:

```
Items\<COMPANY_ID>\Item_1
Items\<COMPANY_ID>\Item_2 and so on
```

[image: Items table]

Users table is defined as:

```
Users\<AUTH_ID>\
```

[image: User table]

Where AUTH_ID is the authentication id

I want to set up rules so that a user can access data only of his own company. How to make read and write rules for Items table (and all other tables too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Items": {
      "$companyId": {
        ".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('CompanyId').val() 
                  === $companyId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In words: allow the authentication user user to read a company's data, if their `CompanyId` matches that company.

Comment: Works fine! Is there a shorthand to apply same rule to another table like 'Product' table?

Comment: You could replace the `"Items"` rule with `"$ItemsOrProducts"`. Rules that start with a `$` apply to each child node for which you don't define an explicit match.